# User-defined class objects in Java TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have a collection (TreeMap), I want to print only one value from the Object im passing. Here is the code that I have being trying

Student.java

```
    class Student {
        int rollno;
        String name;
        int age;
        Student(int rollno,String name,int age){
            this.rollno=rollno;
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
         }

         public String toString(){//overriding the toString() method
             return rollno+" "+name+" "+age;
         }

     }
```

StudentTest.java

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 class StudentTest{
     public static void main(String args[]){

         Map<String,Student> al=new TreeMap<String,Student>();
         al.put("a1",new Student(101,"Vijay",23));
         al.put("a2",new Student(106,"Ajay",27));
         al.put("a3",new Student(105,"Jai",21));


         Set set = al.entrySet();
         // Get an iterator
         Iterator i = set.iterator();

         // Display elements
         while(i.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
             System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
             System.out.println(me.getValue());
         }


         System.out.println(al.get("a1"));

         System.out.println(al.size());

         Set<String> keys =al.keySet();
         for(String key : keys)
             {
                 System.out.println(al.get(key));

             }

        Collection entrySet = al.entrySet();
        Iterator<Student> itr = entrySet.iterator();
        System.out.println("+++++++"+entrySet);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("+++++++"+itr);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
           Student  st = itr.next();
            System.out.println(st.rollno);
        }
    }
}
```

1. I want to print only one value that is either rollno or name or age
2. Also I want to print name as Vijay that is only one name from the
   collection

Please let me know the solution for the error im getting for the code Im trying .

Comment: 1: `me.getValue().rollno`

Comment: immibis me.getValue().rollno will give the error :----                           StudentTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(me.getValue().rollno);
symbol:   variable rollno
  location: class Object

Comment: "Please let me know the solution for the error im getting for the code Im trying . " - what error? Reading error messages is the first step to enlightenment.

Comment: Sorry immibis did nt look at it, I taught it was pasted sorry . The Error is :----                                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Entry
 cannot be cast to Student
        at StudentTest.main(StudentTest.java:42)
Student  st = (Student)itr.next(); // this the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entrySet` of a map is a set of `Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>`s.

You have this:

```
Collection entrySet = al.entrySet();
Iterator<Student> itr = entrySet.iterator();
```

If you weren't using a *raw type* in the first line, the error would be much more obvious. Never use raw types:

```
Collection<Student> entrySet = al.entrySet(); // ERROR HERE - Set<Map.Entry<String, Student>> cannot be cast to Collection<Student>
Iterator<Student> itr = entrySet.iterator();
```

If you want to iterate over the values in your map, use `values`:

```
Collection<Student> entrySet = al.values();
Iterator<Student> itr = entrySet.iterator();
```

Comment: Thank you immibis so much for sharing the correct answer I was looking and also correcting me

Comment: Plus one for "Never use raw types."